# Unity game Within ElectronJS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, electron, exe

Title pretty much covers it. Is there any way to run a game "through" Electron? The idea is to have the unity game somewhere on the computer and open the .exe fil through Electron. Is this even doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js supports running shell functions:

> child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback]);

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('some.exe', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
}
console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated